# Create store url in cms page with URL Key

Tags: 404-page, link

I created a Magento page with an URL Key *condicoes-gerais*. I'm trying to create an hyperlink to that page in a phtml file. I'm using the following command:

```
<a href="<?= $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'condicoes-gerais'))?>"> (Ler condições)</a>
```

When i click the link MAgento redirect page to **404 Not found error**. What is the best option to create the hyperlink?

Comment: can you try <?= $this->getUrl('condicoes-gerais') ?>

Comment: or Mage::getUrl('condicoes-gerais');

Comment: Sukumar's sugestion makes my server jump to mydomain.com/condicoes-gerais/ and it gives an error of page not found. Konrad's sugestion, in my phtml it gives an error saying Mage doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

With `<?= $this->getUrl('condicoes-gerais') ?>` it works. Thanks.